# Is it required to send a response in every request no matter GET or POST in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I defined `my_function` inside `app.post('/someRoute',my_function)` in nodejs which is used for making an http-request(posting data) to another server.

However it seems that `my_function` will run twice when I do not defined any response to the browser inside `my_function`.

What will be the reason for this? And is it required to send a response in every request no matter GET or POST in nodejs?

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated to node.js, any http request to a server should return a proper response. What do you mean it runs twice? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you do not define a response to a function/route handling get or post requests, the request response cycle will not end and thus the request keeps running until it times out because it took too long to get a response from the server. It is thus important to define a response to every request.

Comment: Thanks for your response! And can we extend this "timeout" period to more time?